# Need a python regex that matches (some string)[another string]

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regex, that can be used in python, to parse multiple reddit-style links from a string of text. The format of such links is: (descriptor text)[a URL].

An example text to be parsed can be something like this:

> [google] string0 (google.com) string1 [gmail](gmail.com) string2
>   [hotmail](hotmail.com) string3

From the above text, I'd like to parse the following strings:

1. [gmail](gmail.com)
2. [hotmail](hotmail.com)

I've been trying regex variations that use combinations of \[(.*?)\] and \((.*?)\), but have been generating lots of false positives. Would appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\[[^]]+\]\([^\)]+\)
```

Explaining:

```
\[        # the open '['
[^]]+     # at least one non ']' character
\]        # the end ']'
\(        # the open '('
[^\)]+    # at least one non ')' character
\)        # the end ')'
```

Hope it helps.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/vQ8fP0/2)